# FTP сервис для компании

Tags: ftp, сервер

**Есть задача:**
Публиковать файлы на FTP сервере для публичного доступа другим представительствам или компаниям с которыми мы работаем.

Файлы попадают на FTP либо по прямому закачиванию на FTP через Логин Пароль либо через WEB интерфейс (разработанный под это дело) который является неким FTP файл менеджером.

Скачивать файлы можно по прямой ссылке и сразу начинается скачивание без показа иероглифов (как это делает Опера когда не переданы заголовки на скачивание в браузер)

Возможность докачки

Порылся в Рунете нашел несколько сервисов на Хостинг площадках но ценник там от 500 рублей в месяц за 10 ГГБ - это обдиралово.
Другой предлагает за 1 у.е. в месяц 10 ГГБ но не может предоставить PHP доступ и управление

В компании стоит Сервер Microsoft Windows Server 2003 с большим винчестером, имеет выделенный IP - может на нем можно как то организовать FTP ??

Comment: для компании 500 рублей в месяц обдиралово? ))

Comment: filezilla ставь )

Comment: да ну как - если учесть что средний хостинг на 10 ГГБ в среднем 120 рублей / месяц - там и FTP и все есть ... то тогда просто FTP дешевле еще должен обходиться

Comment: Просто FTP хостеры не продоставляют им это не выгодно, ведь пользователь должен платить деньги за что-то, за место на дисках, за протокол SSH если таковой ему нужен.

Если уж на то пошло гляньте в сторону Облачного сервера, или облачного хранения.

Answer (score 1):

**Serv-U** 
Поставь его себе на сервер. Настрой доступ к нему по IP и чтобы к нему можно было обращаться и все, вот тебе и счастье!

ps
500р для компании в месяц - это копейки.

А если хотите отдельный в нете сервер под это дело, возьмите выделенный сервер, от 1К в месяц, за 2К сожно получить 3Тб*2 винта и хорошую площадку в германии, скорость доступа отличная.

pps а винт на серваке всего 1? т.е. даже не зеркалится никуда? жесть, если это так, то купите еще один такой же и в рейд их соедините, а то будет вам попа.

Comment: арендовать сервер совершенно не обязательно, при наличии, конечно, адекватной серверной... :)

Comment: C этим полностью согласен.
Я от на работе сделал себе нормальный серверный кабинетик, там и стойки стоят, а рядом 1 блок как прокся, пень 3, рядом с ним web сервер тоже простенький, ну и стоит контроллер домена с вытекающими.

Comment: ...и все это на линуксе, ну возможно кроме контроллера ;) 

вообще высовывать наружу мс сервер это плохая затея)

Comment: Да на линуксе все на нем, и контроллер тоже :)
Но до сервак можно только по определенному порту добраться через proxy, собственно как и до остальных системных компов в сети.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы лучше организовал отдельный сервер под "файлопомойку", вряд ли этот МС сервер просто так стоит и ничего не делает...

Comment: Я думаю, компания не выделит денег на файлопомойку, если для них 500р в месяц - это дорого.

Comment: хотя -- да)

Answer (score -1):

godaddy.com вам поможет
$79.68 в год за 150Гб места,
или
$113.88 в год за и unlim места
есть и дешевле предложения там же - смотрите.

Comment: Какой к черту godaddy.com пинг до него как до марса.
Мы в россии находимся, а не на марсе чтобы арендовать сервера непонятно где, гонясь за дешевизной.

113$ и куча геморроя от руководства,"Почему так долго грузится, почему не скачать"

Comment: я использую их сервис для архивирования данных с питерского хостинга, причем данных большого объема, и никаких проблем не наблюдаю. Проект работает уже год. Так что я не уверен что вы понимаете о чем говорите.

Comment: Архивирование данных в архивах и их слитие к дяде в америку - это может и нормально, но постоянно сливать и скачивать с этого сервака - ужасно.

Слить архив было всегда проще \+ если скорость слива не нужна большая-тогда да. Но в данном случае - это не айс.

@kuptsov, хоть с запятыми бы разобрался.

Невыгодно держать проект в питере, а лить данные в америку - долго и неудобно, есть же ближе сервера, Германия к примеру, и пинг лучше и саппорт есть русскоговорящий, который по телефону сможет быстро проконсультировать или исправить проблему.

моё мнение " **godaddy.com  GO HOME**"

Comment: на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные ;) кому удобно, кому нет, к тому же не факт, что питерский хостинг содержит датацентр в питере ;)

Comment: @thunder вообще чущь твой последние комментарий. 1. с составление предложений проблемы. Хостинг не содержит дата центры! А вот в дата центрах можна размещать оборудование и\или арендовать сервера для Хостинга. если нет своих дата центров.

В Питере есть питерские ДатаЦентры селектел тому пример - один из них.

Comment: @Shrek - вы слишком привязываетесь к пингу :) и запятым.
А дядя в Америке на самом деле, как правило безопасней дяди у нас.
В проекте слитие, или лучше сказать залитие, происходит каждые два часа. Данные - это capture с видеокамер. Размер архивов от 200мб и больше. Германия ценник godaddy предложить пока не может. VPS - да, только германия, а вот файлхостинг - наверно все же гоудэдди.